# Column header a link which opens a dialog box

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am unable to create a sub grid column header as a link to another window.

Here is a sample of my code:

```xml
//Function which builds the hyperlink
function buildGridAllUploadURL(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var val = options.rowId;
    alert(val);
    return "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:openDialog(" + val + ")'>" +  "Upload" + "<a>";          
} 

//function for dialog window
function openDialog(Id) {
    var upload_url = '<s:property value="uploadUrl"/>';
    $("#cpp_upload").load(upload_url+"?id="+Id);
    // $("#cpp_upload").HTMLFieldSetElement = $("#cpp_upload").dialog('open');
}

<sj:dialog id="cpp_upload" title="Notes" autoOpen="false"
           modal="false" height="300" width="500"
           buttons="{
                    'Submit':function() { okButton(); },
                    'Cancel':function() { cancelButton(); }
                    }">
</sj:dialog>
<sjg:grid id="cpp" subGridUrl="%{url}" gridModel="gridModel"
          viewsortcols="[true, 'vertical', true]" rowNum="9999"
          timeout="35" pager="false" navigator="false"
          cssStyle="underline" cssClass="link" draggable="true">

    <sjg:gridColumn name="A" index="A" title="Upload"
                    formatter="buildGridAllUploadURL"
                    align="center" width="100" sortable="false"/> 
    <sjg:gridColumn name="B" index="B" title="B" formatter="URL"
                    cssClass="link" cssStyle="underline" align="center" 
                    width="100" sortable="false"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

1. Requirement: I need to make the highlighted item as hyperlink opening to a new dialog etc window on a click. The `sjg:gridcolumn` provides with very limited options.
2. My approach: I have tried with fetching the header location. I am not able to get the header by its ID either.

Heres an image of what I am trying to achieve.
[image: Grid]

Comment: Removed tags from the title, reformatted the title to be short and to the point. Formatted the code to be clean an readable. Moved the text at the top of the question out of the code block. Used the preferred number formatting. Correctly attached the image to the post.

Comment: You need the upload header to become an hyperlink ?

Comment: Yes Andrea thats the requirement.